# How to get information in and out of a Smart Panel PXTextEdit box

Tags: acumatica

I have a customization that uses a Smart Panel containing a PXTextEdit box that is used to edit the text in a grid's custom user field.  In other words, when a new (custom) action button at the header of the grid is clicked, the Smart Panel pops up and allows editing of a large amount of text via the PXTextEdit box. I've gotten this to work, mechanically. The problem is that I want this to:

1.)  Have the PXTextEdit box contain the text of a specific custom user field located in the grid when the Smart Panel opens.

2.)  Have the text that is edited in the Smart Panel's PXTextEdit field transferred to the grid's custom user field when the OK button is clicked on the Smart Panel.

I have no idea how to get the text in or out of the Smart Panel's PXTextEdit box using the graph extension business logic.

Here is my code so far:

```cs
public class SOOrderEntryExt : PXGraphExtension<SOOrderEntry>
{
    public PXSelect<SOLine,
            Where<SOLine.orderType, Equal<Current<SOLine.orderType>>,
            And<SOLine.orderNbr, Equal<Current<SOLine.orderNbr>>,
            And<SOLine.lineNbr, Equal<Current<SOLine.lineNbr>>>>>> MyPanelView;

    public PXAction<SOOrder> noteAction;
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Add Note", MapViewRights = PXCacheRights.Select, MapEnableRights = PXCacheRights.Update)]
    [PXButton(ImageKey = PX.Web.UI.Sprite.Main.DataEntryF)]
    protected virtual IEnumerable NoteAction(PXAdapter adapter)
    {
        if (Base.Transactions.Current != null &&
            MyPanelView.AskExt() == WebDialogResult.OK)
        {
            //extra stuff here if needed when OK is pushed

        }

        return adapter.Get();
    }
}
```

Here is the aspx code for the panel:

```
 <px:PXSmartPanel runat="server" ID="PXSmartPanelNote" DesignView="Hidden" LoadOnDemand="true" CreateOnDemand="false" CaptionVisible="true" Caption="Order Notes" Key="MyPanelView" AcceptButtonID="btnMyNoteOk">
     <px:PXFormView runat="server" ID="formMyNote" CaptionVisible="False" Width="100%" DataSourceID="ds" DataMember="MyPanelView">
       <Template>
         <px:PXLayoutRule runat="server" ID="PXLayoutRule44" StartColumn="True" LabelsWidth="S" ControlSize="XL" />
         <px:PXTextEdit runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine" DataField="Note"  ID="cstNote" Width="400" Height="400" />
       </Template>
     </px:PXFormView>
     <px:PXPanel runat="server" ID="PXPanel10" SkinID="Buttons">
        <px:PXButton runat="server" ID="btnMyNoteOk" Text="OK" DialogResult="OK" />
     </px:PXPanel>
 </px:PXSmartPanel>
```

I've also added the callback command:

```
 <px:PXDSCallbackCommand CommitChanges="true" Name="NoteAction" Visible="False" DependOnGrid="grid" /></CallbackCommands>
```

and the grid header button to open the Smart Panel:

```
 <px:PXToolBarButton Text="Add Note" DependOnGrid="grid">
<AutoCallBack Command="NoteAction" Target="ds" /></px:PXToolBarButton>
```

Comment: Can you show the aspx code of the panel?

Comment: I've added that to the question - see above

Comment: Looks like it should work fine like that.

Comment: It doesn't show the note text when I open the panel, and it doesn't put the text from the SmartPanel into the grid when I close it (even after refreshing the grid).  So, essentially, the only thing that works is that the Panel opens and closes.

Comment: I managed to make your code work by using a custom field added on SOOrder, but with SOLine it was empty for me too. I haven't tried it myself but I would suggest to add that action to the details grid instead of the toolbar, I have a feeling that the `Current` should synch correctly that way.

Comment: try to add SyncPosition="True"  to the  px:PXGrid definition.

Comment: The button is on the Action bar the grid level, not the header.  Sorry - my terms were probably confusing - unless I misunderstand your comment "add that action to the details grid instead of the toolbar"...

Comment: SyncPosition="True" was already set for the grid.

Comment: Is that question a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39373707/add-extra-note-field-to-grid-line ?

Comment: Yes - because I don't know if the comments prompt further exploration into the issue by the replying party.  I added comments to the other case, but had no responses, so this is what I assumed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your DataField name is wrong. you want to use "UsrNote" and not the existing "Note" field in your smartpanel.

```
DataField="UsrNote"
```

this is reference to the original post were you had the following for your field you are trying to work with...

```
#region UsrNote 
[PXDBString(4000, IsUnicode = true, InputMask = "")]
[PXUIField(DisplayName = "Note")] 
public virtual string UsrNote { get; set; } 
public class usrNote : PX.Data.IBqlField { } 
#endregion
```

Comment: I was able to test and confirm changing the DataField to UsrNote and include the code you have that this works. I added the field to the grid and what was updated in the panel also shows updated on the grid (and same in reverse). Hope this helps.